# Проблема с контроллером Laravel - "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"

Tags: laravel

При попытке открытия "../posts/**create**", появляется ошибка:

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: С:\OSPanel\domains\blog.loc\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

Почему он ругается на шаблон **show,** когда должен вызывать **create** я не знаю. Шаблон **create** пустой.
При этом и первый и второй роут работают хорошо.

Возможно проблема в функции show, видимо при наборе "../posts/create", create он воспринимает как переменную $url и обрабатывает методом show

Роуты:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
```

Контроллер:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Posts::simplePaginate(10);
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}

public function show($url)
{
    $post = Posts::where(['url'=>$url])->first();
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('posts.create');
}
```

Comment: `Route::get('/posts/show/{post}', 'PostsController@show');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не собираетесь менять структуру маршрутов, то попробуйте поменять их местами следующим образом:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
```

Хотя по факту у вас конфликт маршрутов и этого желательно избегать.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало. Не знал, что очередность важна и что всё так просто, пол дня промучался.
В итоге стал использовать:  `Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');`

Answer (score 0):

Ругается в show потому, что шаблон роута '/posts/create' попадает под шаблон '/posts/{post}' и пытается найти пост с $url='create'. Не находит и возвращает null. Соответственно выводит ошибку, что null не является объектом и у него нет поля title